# Difference between try/catch vs then/catch with axiom

Tags: promise, callback, async-await, axios, try-catch

Trying to understand what is difference between these all with respect to `axios` library.

```
function doSomething() {
  axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => process(response))
    .catch((error) => handle(error))
}
```

vs

```
async function doSomething() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    process(response);
  } catch(error) {
    handle(error);
  }
}
```

vs

```
async function doSomething() {
  return await axios.get(url);
}
```

vs

```
function doSomething() {
  return axios.get(url);
}
```

Trying to understands this and write wrapper for axios calls for the consumer.

Thanks.

Comment: The latter two obviously do not call `process` and `handle`?!

Comment: If you add some `return` statements in the first and second snippet, they become equivalent.